# How to highlight just first row of table in ng-repeat angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

so i want to highlight just the row on the top of the table with different color using ng-repeat.
This is my code:

```
<table class="table table-hover" style="font-size:14px; margin-left: 5px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left;"><data-i18n i18n="_m_f_pen_feeding_start_date_">Feeding date</data-i18n></th>
     <th style="text-align: left;"><data-i18n i18n="_m_f_pen_frequency_of_feeding_">Frequency of feeding</data-i18n></th>
      </tr>
       </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="freq in vm.details.pen_feeding_scheduler_list | orderBy:'-start_feeding_date'">
           <td style="min-width: 120px; text-align: left;">{{freq.start_feeding_date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
            <td style="min-width: 120px; text-align: left;  display: inline-block;white-space: nowrap">
            {{freq.feeding_frequency || ('_label_empty_' | i18n)}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
```

And this is how my table looks:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy2kI.png).
Any idea for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add colour for your table header row?

Comment: For the tr where i use ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

say you have color's array:

```
$scope.colors = ['yellow']
```

then you can use that:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-style="{'background-color': colors[$index]}">
```

Comment: And it will change bg color of each row, i need to change just for first

Comment: You can pass index that you want as every row has particular index!

Comment: @JoviBon did you check using your code in that way? let me know if you face any issues

Answer (score 0):

It must work for you `<tr ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-class="$index===0?'hover':''">`  ........
(`hover` is class name)

Answer (score 0):

ng-style="$index == 0 ? {'color': 'cadetblue'} : {}" is the solution